# GuessIt - Web API Curl Request in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, get

I'm trying to get the following cURL request working. The command line cURL GET request as shown on the API page is:

```
curl "http://guessit.io/guess?filename=House.of.Cards.2013.S02E03.1080p.NF.WEBRip.DD5.1.x264-NTb.mkv"
```

The page for the web API is: http://api.guessit.io/

My code so far is:

```
<?php

$url = "http://guessit.io/guess?filename=";

//This adds a filename to the URL 
$theurl = $url . $current->name;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$theurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$result = file_get_contents($theurl);
// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

echo $resp;
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

What type of response will I get? Is it JSON?

The more important question I have is: what is the right code for getting a response with this API in PHP?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE: The answer is correct, but the bad gateway response was because the web service API was not working at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an HTML response for a `502 Bad Gateway` error. Going to "http://guessit.io" also shows a `502`.

Here is the same curl request executed in terminal:

```
$ curl "http://guessit.io/guess?filename=House.of.Cards.2013.S02E03.1080p.NF.WEBRip.DD5.1.x264-NTb.mkv"
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is some info [about the 502 error](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm).

Comment: Thanks, and how do I get the correct code in PHP to get a proper response?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by proper response. The response will be a 502 error regardless of whatever means you use to do the request. It doesn't look like the guessit service is working.